# Retain Selected value in dropdown -Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retain a selected value in the dropdown after posting the page.

**Description of scenario**

These are my dropdown options

```
<select id="JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom">
<option value="17:00">17:00</option>
<option value="18:00">18:00</option>
</select>
```

Before submitting the Page, I am assigning the value to a variable using the below line.

```
var selectedVal=$("#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom")
```

After submitting the page the same dropdown should retail its value.

I do not want to change in options, but want to display the selected value after posting the form.

**I have used this one:**

This is adding anew option to the dropdown.

```
$('#JqueryDDownForAvailableTo').append('<option selected="true" value='+selectedValTo+'>' +selectedValTo + '</option>')
```

**I have used this one**

This is not selecting the selected value:

```
  $('#JqueryDDownForAvailableTo').val(selectedValTo);
```

I tried to find on google but failed.

Any assistance please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for getting selected value

```
var selectedVal = $("#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom").val();
```

for setting selected value

```
$("#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom").val(selectedVal);
```

hope this helps you

Comment: @RajKumar: I need to populate the selected value, which is retaining the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

For single select dom elements, to get the currently selected value:

```
$('#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom:selected').text();
```

Comment: try $("#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom option:selected").val();

Answer (score 0):

To retain selected value after submitting form to php

```
 <select id="JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom" name="JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom"><option value="17:00">17:00</option><option value="18:00">18:00</option>
```

```
$('#JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom').val(<?php echo $_POST['JqueryDDownForAvailableFrom'];?>)
```